# SYSAUX tablespace with non existing datafile

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Every five minutes, oracle engine returns an error into trc files where it says the message:
'ORA-00376:   File '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_2/dbs/MISSING00002' cannot be read at this time'.
This file doesn't exist and if i check which one is the tablespace where is located i can see that is sysaux.
If i check for all datafiles of sysaux tablespace, only this appears with status 'RECOVER'.
If i try to delete it it returns me the error that is the only file of tablespace, and if i add a new datafile and try to delete,  it returns me the error saying that is the first datafile of tablespace.
I can't drop tablespace because it returns me the error that can't be deleted.
What could i do? Making an export of all database and import it should work, but this would be the last option.

Answer (score 1):

"MISSINGXXX" datafile essentially tells you that Oracle is not able to find the correct file (maybe you moved or deleted the actual data file). "Missing" isn't an actual file.
If you have an RMAN backup, you can try restoring the file from backup (you could use recovery advisor to achieve this), or if you think you know where the actual file is you could run "rename" datafile procedure to point to the correct file: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17120/dfiles005.htm

Answer (score 0):

RMAN Data Recovery Advisor can help you out.

```
rman target /

# data recovery advisor (DRA)
list failure all;
advise failure;
repair failure preview;
repair failure; (you will be promted)
```

Best of luck!

Comment: No backup is avaiable. The list failure returns the error that dbf is missing. and advise failure returns me that the only manual actions are: restoring dbf from a backup and contact with oracle support